# Can you help me identify this Italian Royal Army Uniform?

Tags: military, identification, uniform, women, italian

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/973bD.jpg)These are three silver gelatin photograph, each measuring 9 x 6 3/4 inches. I have a total of five photos: three different images, two are repeats. In two of the images, the subject is posing with a woman in a dress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am a cataloguer at an auction house and would like to accurately describe the time period and uniform in the photo. I am also intrigued by the idea that the person in the photograph may have been assigned the female gender at birth but was living a different lifestyle and perhaps passing as a cis gender man to serve in the army, although I am aware that the photos may have just been taken for fun.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it my imagination, or does the face appear female? Unlikely, but...?

Comment: @TheHonRose - Form does too IMHO, but that's beside the point of the question, so probably none of our concern (unless the poster chooses to make it so).

Comment: Perhaps this is is theatrical costume?

Comment: I do believe that the subject is female @TheHonRose

Comment: I was wondering whether she might have been in the medical corps, and whether a woman would have been allowed to serve in any branch of the Italian military in this period

Comment: Riding crop and jodhpurs are typical medical corps garb.

Comment: @T.E.D With respect, I believe it **is** relevant, given the general, if not universal, historical ban on women serving in most military forces, until very recently. This is PC gone mad!

Comment: @TheHonRose - Well, my main concern here was avoiding deluging the poor poster with unasked for speculations about the "manliness" of their ancestor, which would be kinda gross if it actually is a (presumably really young) dude. Some folks might take that kind of thing as a personal attack.

Comment: @TheHonRose - However, given the further info from the author, you are clearly correct that it is relevant. Devonista, can we get some more of what you already know and suspect about this picture edited into the question please? Comments are good for hashing things out like this, but ultimately we would like as much info as possible about this picture **in the question** itself.

Comment: @devonista Are you able to upload any of the other photographs? More or different images may be helpful.

Comment: Background of the photo is interesting . . . women's apparel. How about "I bet I could fit into that uniform." And so she could since it is too large for her. Look at the seat of the pants reflected in the mirror. Also the rings on the fingers appear to be of a feminine design. Since there were no women in the Italian Army at the time can it be unreasonable to presume the photo was made in jest? Back in the days before women would be admitted, on more than one occasion, I saw attractive young women don a USMA or VMI uniform as joke or maybe, perhaps, to sneak into barracks

Comment: @RLeonard - I agree on all points. Whilst it may, as the OP suggests, be a cis female passing as a man to serve in the army, I strongly suspect it was a "dressing up" joke. And Viralk believes the rank to be that of Major, which the subject appears to be far too young for. Given the rings you mention, I cannot help but wonder if this is a woman wearing her fiancé's uniform - which is, admittedly, to go way beyond the evidence! ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose Rings one can change in seconds. Given the state of the finger *nails* (1st pic) I'd say that actual mil service might be fully out of the question? On the other hand, the clearly 'dressed as female' person makes our subject appear quite tall.

Comment: Or our subject makes her look short.  True one can change rigs in a second, but, and not that there were all that many, I've never been able to get a woman's ring on anything but my little finger . . . my wife's included.

Comment: @LangLangC - true, but as a 5ft tall female, I'd make virtually **anyone** look tall! :D

Answer (score 3):

It's a world war one era "Regio Esercito" (Italian army) uniform like the ones you can see [here](http://www.pietrigrandeguerra.it/pietri-amedeo/pietri-amedeo-foto-militare/).

the ranks on the cuff confirm the WW1 era (by design) and indicate the rank of Major, confirming this we have the jacket with pockets that was supplied only to the officers as the troops were without them.
[Rank of WW1 Italian Army (In Italian)](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradi_del_Regio_Esercito#Ufficiali_superiori_2)

The uniform worn is the gray-green model of 1909 the standard for the troops of the time.

[image]

Unfortunately, without seeing the color on the collar, it is impossible to determine exactly which regiment it belonged to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough reply. I am assuming that such a rank would not be available to women at this time. Can you confirm this for me?

Comment: @devonista women can only join the Italian army since 1999 so during WW1 was impossible for a woman to have a combat role, the only women you could find near the trenches were nurses from the red cross who had their own separate ranks https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpo_delle_infermiere_volontarie_della_Croce_Rossa_Italiana

Comment: The uniform in the original picture looks pristine too. As if is hasn't seen much, if any, use prior to the picture being taken. However, it *does* look well-fitted to the wearer, not like she's(?) wearing some other guy's uniform.

Comment: Well-fitted it does *not* look to me. The belt does a lot what the cut doesn't do. Also: notice the *unbuttoned* pockets!

Comment: @LangLangC - I agree, the 'Sam Brown' belt is cinched very tightly!